# Slick carousel images not fitting on screen vertically and not centered vertically

Tags: jquery, html, css, slick.js

I'm using the Slick jquery carousel library to display single images that are lazy loaded.

Images are loading and displaying OK, and they are fitting the screen horizontally and centered horizontally.

The issue I'm having is I cannot get the images to shrink to fit the screen vertically (when they are larger than the screen height) and cannot get them to center vertically (when they are shorter than the screen height.)

Ideally I would like Slick to responsively fit itself to a parent div.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.image-slider').slick({
        lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        initialSlide: 1,
        centerMode: true,
        arrows: false,
        dots: true,
      });

    });
```

I have a JS Fiddle of the code here...
[JS Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/Z_Stark/gfspwcyo/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got your question right, you want Slick carousel to adapt to the height of the images.

To do that you can edit the Javascript and add this line `adaptiveHeight: true`
The new JavaScript should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.image-slider').slick({
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    initialSlide: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
    adaptiveHeight: true //add this line
  });
});
```

Here's the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gfspwcyo/17/

Comment: No that is not the issue. The issue is if the image is taller than available screen space it does not shrink to fit, instead a vertical scroll bar appears. (See the image with the baby bunny and the duck as an example, it goes off the bottom of the screen.)

Comment: @Z.Stark okay in that case you have to overwrite some slick CSS properties. Because the default height of the slick slider is set to `100%` and hence it take on the size of the image and that's why the image does not shrink to fit. Set the height of the slider to a fixed value like this: `.slick-slide {
    height: 300px;
}` this will keep a constant size of the slider and the images inside it will also shrink to fit the carousal height. Here's the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gfspwcyo/18/. Let me know if this helps.